# Catch mako runtime errors using Bottle

Tags: python, bottle, mako

I'm looking for a way to catch mako runtime errors using Bottle.

Runtime errors in python are catched using the following code:

```py
# main.py
from lib import errors
import bottle

app = bottle.app()
app.error_handler = errors.handler
...

# lib/errors.py
from bottle import mako_template as template

def custom500(error):
    return template('error/500')

handler = {
    500: custom500
}
```

This works flawlessly, as exceptions are turned into 500 Internal Server Error.

I'd like to catch the mako runtime errors in a similar fashion, does anyone have a clue of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to catch `mako.exceptions.SyntaxException`.

This code works for me:

```
@bottle.route('/hello')
def hello():
    try:
        return bottle.mako_template('hello')

    except mako.exceptions.SyntaxException as exx:
        return 'mako exception: {}\n'.format(exx)
```

---

EDIT: Per your comment, here are some pointers on how to install this globally.  Install a [bottle plugin](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html) that wraps your functions in the mako.exceptions.SyntaxException try block.

Something along these lines:

```
@bottle.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return bottle.mako_template('hello')

def catch_mako_errors(callback):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return callback(*args, **kwargs)
        except mako.exceptions.SyntaxException as exx:
            return 'mako exception: {}\n'.format(exx)
    return wrapper

bottle.install(catch_mako_errors)
```

Comment: Aha, I didn't know you could do that. But what if there are many routes? Do I have to do the same thing on all routes, or can it be performed globally somehow?

Comment: If you want to catch them globally, you can install a bottle plugin.  I'll update my answer with some references which will point the way.

Comment: Done--I've added code that works globally to my original answer.  Did that do the trick?

Comment: Just tried your first suggestion, without success. The second one allows me to catch python exceptions, but not mako.

Comment: I found my problem! I've been using `debug=True` when starting bottle. When debug is enabled, mako exceptions are catched within bottle and a custom error page is showed. By removing it, the exception is not handled inside bottle and I can catch it myself.